# Find a case's open date using API

Tags: soql, rest-api, api, soap-api, case

I'm fetching case details using the Salesforce API. I am trying to get the date the case was opened (the 'Date/Time Opened' column when viewing cases in SF service console).

However, reading through [this documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_case.htm), I see `ClosedDate` but nothing related to `OpenedDate`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no field called OpenedDate. You're simply looking for CreatedDate. The "label" for CreatedDate is Opened Date/Time. You can verify this by going to Setup > Customize > Cases.

[image: Date/Time Opened]